# Node Beginner: User input on a webpage to alter JSON request?

Tags: javascript, node.js, dom, user-input

I have a text input field on my webpage, `userID` in which the user specifies a bit of information that will be appended to a JSON request. The function `fetchJSON` is called when the user submits their info.

The code is as follows:

```
function fetchJSON(){
    //get user input
    var userID = document.getElementById("userID").value;
    //create request and options
    var https= require("https");
    var options = {
        host: "api.example.com",
        path: "/GetHistory/V001/account_id=" + userID,
        method: "GET"
    };

    //handle request
    var request = https.request(options, function(response){
        var body = "";
        response.on("data", function(chunk){
            body += chunk.toString("utf8");
        });
        response.on("end", function(){
            var json = JSON.parse(body);
            console.log(json);
        });
    });
    request.end();
}
```

The code works when I run it from terminal with the userID hardcoded (`node main.js`) but I am in the dark as to how I can run it from a webpage with user defined input.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: node.js javascript, can't manipulate DOM..its server-side, you have to send somehow to backend this kind of information maybe using http requests _usually_ but it doesn't seem  that you use any kind of http server..

Comment: @Phoenix I am looking into express to solve this. Is that advisable? Thanks!

Comment: yes express is amazing framework, and easy too learn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, **node.js** can't manipulate the client-side DOM.

So you need to pass the variable to server, so using `express` *as mentioned in the comments* after you have generated a basic website

setup a basic `get` route

```
app.get('/api/getprofilebyid/:id',function(req,res){
     //get user input
    var userID = req.params.id; //document.getElementById("userID").value;
    //create request and options
    var https= require("https");
    var options = {
        host: "api.example.com",
        path: "/GetHistory/V001/account_id=" + userID,
        method: "GET"
    };

    //handle request
    var request = https.request(options, function(response){
        var body = "";
        response.on("data", function(chunk){
            body += chunk.toString("utf8");
        });
        response.on('error',function(err){
         res.json(500,{'error':err}); // an error occured.
        });
        response.on("end", function(){
          request.end(); // and the request.
          res.json(200,body); // output json
        });
    });
});
```

and request using ajax or simply browse to url..

using jQuery ajax `$.get` on client-side

```
 var userID = document.getElementById("userID").value;
$.get('/api/getprofilebyid/'+userID,function(response){
 // handle response
});
```

Comment: Wonderful, thank you! *scurries off to learn about express*

Thanks again!